# jQuery mobile issues getting url of current page (works fine on chrome desktop)

Tags: jquery-mobile

Any idea why:

```
$('#site-toggle').live('tap', function () {
    url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl("http://" + window.location.host.replace('m.','') + window.location.pathname);
    window.location.href=url.href;
});
```

works on chrome on desktop but not on my Android?

On Chrome it gets the page you are now on but on my Android it will always redirect to first page that was loaded.

Comment: this is within the pagecreate event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#site-toggle').live('tap', function () {
 var fullSiteURL = 'http://' + location.host.replace('m.', '') +  $(e.target).attr('data-url');
 window.location.href = fullSiteURL;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just running a `replace` on the `window.location.href` property?

```
$('#site-toggle').live('tap', function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('m.','');
});
```

Comment: On Android still will load the first page you visited rather then the page you are on (I have default jQuery Mobile ajax navigation on)